# How to drag text which is printed over Image (in canvas) using mouse in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, mouse, draggable

I want to add a **Drag Text Feature** in canvas to change the position of text using mouse.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageFont,ImageDraw,ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Demo')
root.geometry('400x50')

def func_image():

    img_window = tk.Toplevel()
    img_window.grab_set()

    photo = Image.open(r'E:\side_300.png')
    wi,hi = photo.size
    fonty = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',18)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(photo)
    draw.text((50,50),text=text.get(),fill='red',font=fonty)
    new_photo = photo
    can_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_photo)

    canvas = tk.Canvas(img_window,height=500,width=500)
    canvas.pack(anchor='n')
    canvas.create_image(wi/2,hi/2,image=can_photo,anchor='center')
    img_window.mainloop()

lbl_text = tk.Label(root,text='Enter Text :')
lbl_text.grid(row=0,column=0)

text = tk.Entry()
text.grid(row=0,column=1)

btn = tk.Button(root,text='Click Me',command=func_image)
btn.grid(row=0,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

When you run the code it will firstly open a window with name 'Demo' which contains one entry box and a button.
When you click on a Button 'Click Me' after entering some text into entry box it will go to a function **func_image** and opens a new window which contain a canvas filled with new_image.

Comment: I don't see a text object. Are you referring to the image that contains some text? I don't see any code related to dragging the text (or image). What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Disclaimer: I don't have a lot of experience with PIL, so i don't know how to remove text that has already been drawn. Maybe you can figure that one out yourself. But apart from that, i know some things about tkinter. My idea would be the following:

Bind a function to the `<B1-motion>` event (Button 1 is being held down and moved) that will constantly get the position of the mouse inside the window and draw new text at that position, while deleting the previous text.

```
    import...
    ...

    def func_image():
        img_window = tk.Toplevel()
        ...
        ...
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(photo)
        draw.text((50,50),text=text.get(),fill='red',font=fonty)
        ...
        def move_text(event):
            # here you would delete your previous text
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            draw.text((x,y),text=text.get(),fill='red',font=fonty

        img_window.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_text)
```

That being said, i think it would be a better idea to use `Canvas.create_text` (more on [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method)) in order to write your text on the image. It's really easy to drag around text on a `Canvas`, here's a little example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def change_position(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y

    # 20x20 square around mouse to make sure text only gets targeted if the mouse is near it
    if text in c.find_overlapping(str(x-10), str(y-10), str(x+10), str(y+10)):
        c.coords(text, x, y)  # move text to mouse position

c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.pack(anchor='n')

text = c.create_text('10', '10', text='test', fill='red', font=('arial', 18))  # you can define all kinds of text options here
c.bind("<B1-Motion>", change_position)

root.mainloop()
```